# HIVE Query - Loading data into HIVE Table

Tags: hive

I have a dataset (txt file) in which there are 10 columns from which, last column has string data separated by a tab. for example -> abcdef      lkjhj     pqrst...wxyz

I created a new table defining col 10 as STRING but after loading the data into this table and I verify the data it shows only abcdef populated in the last column and the rest are ignored.

Plz can someone help how do I load entire string of data in the hive table. Do I need to write UDF ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the code you are using to load the dataset

Comment: also add `create table` statement that you use to create you table

Comment: Are the columns separated by tabs as well?

Comment: create table statement is;   Create table test1(vid_id STRING, vid_upl STRING, upl_int INT, vid_cat STRING, len_vid INT, num_viws INT, rat_vid FLOAT, num_rat INT, num_cmt INT, rel_vid STRING)
row identifier delimited fields terminated by '\t'
STORED AS textfile;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH \filepath into table test1;

Comment: columns are separated by tab and the last column (rel_vid) has multiple string data which is separated by tab even.